# How to loop over directory and append to a master file?

Tags: python

I have a monthly file stored in monthly folders on my windows machine like this:

```
C:\customer\201811\cust_data_201811.xls
C:\customer\201812\cust_data_201812.xls
C:\customer\201901\cust_data_201901.xls
...
```

This will keep growing as the year progresses.
I need to write a python program that will iterate over these directories, read each of these files and keep appending to a master file which will be written out to a separate xls file.
How can I do it?

Comment: What have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about the formatting of the output, I can help with reading in each of the worksheets in the directory.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

def parse_folder(folder_path):

    # Loop over files in path
    for f in os.listdir(folder_path):

        # Construct full path
        f_path = folder_path + "\\" + f + "\\cust_data_" + f + ".xlsx"

        # Read the workbook and store information into pandas dataframe
        # See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html for options
        wkbk = pd.read_excel(os.path.abspath(f_path), header=0)

        # // Do whatever needs to be done to the file here //


if __name__ == "__main__":
    folder_path = os.path.abspath("C:\\customer\\")
    parse_folder(folder_path)
```

This function will loop over each of the files in your directory and read them all in with pandas read_excel(). The variable wkbk is a pandas dataframe, which can be parsed for whatever information you need in it.

For outputting the data from each file I would recommend looking into xlsxwriter if you want to compile all of the information and output it to a master excel sheet. The limitation with xlsxwriter is that it cannot append to existing files, only write out completely new ones. A workaround to this reading in the current master list and then rewriting it in the new file.